# http error 500 aws bitnami wordpress hosting

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, cloud-hosting

I had a website hosted on godaddy but I wasn't convinced with their hosting performance so I wanted to shift on aws. I created an aws es2 instance and and launched a wordpress blog with the help of bitnami ami. Then I exported wordpress tables from godaddy db and all the files present in htdocs folder. I uploaded all the files to new aws hosting with the help of filezilla, deleted the tables in already present bitnami_wordpress db and imported my old tables in that db and I didn't mess with wp-config.php file as it was already set acc to preinstalled bitnami_wordpress db. All these processes are gathered from internet. But I still can't access my blog as I get HTTP error 500."Your site is unable to handle the request." I have basic subscription plan so can't access aws support. Have I performed all the steps correctly? Plz help. Thanks.

Comment: *Check............ your............ logs.*. It's a server error.

Comment: Where can I find the logs?

Comment: I found a error_log file in the htdocs folder but the last log that was there was of a date 15 days ago and I started experiencing the error about 2-3 days ago.